# How to balance speakers using a microphone?

Tags: windows-8, audio, speakers, microphone

I am sure in a past version of windows I was able to balance the left and right speaker by using a microphone. However, in windows 8 I do not see this feature in the sound control panel.

It may have been windows vista. I recall initiating the balance operation which involved a wizard that instructed me to have a quiet room and to place a microphone near where my head would be. The speakers would play sample sounds like pings and calculate and set the balance using the sample as listened by the microphone.

How can I do this in windows 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sounds -> Playback -> (select your playback device) -> Properties -> Enhancements -> (check Room Correction) -> Settings`

The `Enhancements` tab however doesn't seem to be available i.e. for my built-in laptop speakers.

Comment: I have to uninstall the Realtek Control Panel (just so only the driver is present) and then the room correction option appeared where you stated.

Comment: Perhaps Realtek Control Panel has got some internal room correction service incorporating/overriding system's default.